# The source attachment does not contain the source for the file JSON.class

Tags: java, json, mongodb

This there anything wrong with my code? I'm new to Java and i'm trying to import a file into MongoDB. However there is a error that i have no idea what is it. I am using Eclipse.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;
import com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException;



public class readwrite {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException,JSONParseException{

        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("actualdata");
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("metadata");

        String line = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = null;
            try {
                fstream = new FileInputStream("/home/Output/json1-100000-all");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("File does not exist, exiting");
                return;
            }

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                DBObject dbObject;
                sb.append(dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(bufferedReader.readLine()));
                collection.insert(dbObject);

                DBCursor cursorDoc = collection.find();
                while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(cursorDoc.next());
                }
            }       

            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file");              
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file");                  
            }
    }


}
```

This is the error that is displayed

```
[
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{
 ^
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:272)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:230)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:195)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:145)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:81)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:66)
    at readwrite.main(readwrite.java:45)
```

It show me this error when i clicked on  at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:272) where it says that the Source is not found. The source attachment does not contain the source for the file JSON.class.
I can print the output of BufferedReader if i did not included the conversion of DBObject. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would appear that the JSON you are trying to "parse" is not all on one line.

Comment: How would you suggest me to do?

Comment: Might be worth posting your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 0):

1) Didn't you mean to write JSON.parse(line)
instead of JSON.parse(bufferedReader.readLine())) ?
This might cause it to try and parse 'null' at the last iteration

2)  If that doesn't help, could you get the exact string value of 'line' on the failed iteration? (this should be easy using debugger or simple printing to system out)

Regards

Comment: Hi , sorry because i'm new to Java. Do you have examples of what you meant by debugger or simple print to system out? I am able to print out if i were to delete away DBObject dbObject;
                sb.append(dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(bufferedReader.readLine()));
                collection.insert(dbObject);

Comment: But I just meant "System.out.println(line);"  just before the existing "sb.append(dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(...". Because it complains about being unable to parse the line, so we want to see the content of that line...